# Eroor 404s to /admin/host/ping after turning on automatic scale out in App Service?

Tags: azure

Does anyone have any information on what the "/admin/host/ping" is doing, or how to adjust it to reach an other path? Although I'd prefer to keep utilizing automated scale out, I'm a little concerned about this ping.

I set a scale out limit and enabled automated scale out for some of my app services. I notice a pretty consistent GET to "/admin/host/ping" when I look at app insights. Since it began at the same time, I assume it is a component of the automatic scale out infrastructure; nevertheless, it persists even if I disable automatic scale out.

Everything else appears to be operating according to plan.

Does anyone have any information on what the "/admin/host/ping" is doing, or how to adjust it to reach an other path? Although I'd prefer to keep utilizing automated scale out, I'm a little concerned about this ping. Hi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this errors are caused by autoscaling and pinging the endpoints for both functions apps and web apps. as this is still in preview I guess this will be taken care of in future,

it doesn't affect the scaleing,so you are good, and below is the link to the detailed note on azure QandA platform, give it a try for more info thanks.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1457153/seeing-a-lot-of-404s-to-admin-host-ping-after-turn